# Как правильно задать route для ссылки?

Tags: angularjs

Использую `$routeProvider` в Angular JS:
Пытаюсь задать ссылки для route:

Ссылки вида:

- http://taok.com/profile#personal
- http://taok.com/profile#contacts

Для `when` указал:

```
.when('/#personal/:param', {
   templateUrl: '/personal.html',
   controller: 'EditController'
})
```

Но это не сработало...

Так же пробовал:

```
.when('/test', {
      templateUrl: 'education.html',
       controller: 'EditController'
})
```

Для ссылки:

```
<a href="test">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> .when('/#personal/:param', {
> ```

```
.when('/personal/:param', {
```

> ```
> <a href="test">
> ```

```
<a href="#/test">
```